# How to read a JSON file in a Heroku application

Tags: python, flask, insomnia

I have a flask app and I can run it locally with no problem.

I can also run this flask app on Heroku if I remove the first three lines in my app.py and simply return a string (e.g., "Hello").

Therefore, I am mostly sure that the problem lies in the first three lines of webhook function. However, it works fine locally so I am not sure why it fails when I use it in Heroku (perhaps I did not very well understood how Heroku works)

I tested the code locally with insomnia. The structure of my input is a dictionary in insomnia. When I tested locally, request.data has a binary format. This is why I converted it into json file to use json.loads()

The Heroku error is "Internal Server Error"

I will appreciate any suggestion on how to resolve this.

```
{
"passphrase": "somelongstring123",
"time": "2020-09-05T19:47:00Z",
"ticker": "AAPL",
"bar": {
    "time": "2020-09-05T19:46:00Z",
    "open": 126.35,
    "volume": 12345
},
"strategy": {
    "position_size": 171,
    "order_action": "buy",
    "order_contracts": 171,
    "prev_market_position_size": 1
}}
```

The structure of my code

```
folder
-app.py
-Procfile 
-requirements.txt
-other files
```

app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import config, json
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])

def webhook():
    webhook_message = request.data
    my_json = webhook_message.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    webhook_message = json.loads(my_json)
    return str(webhook_message)
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

requirements.txt file

```
flask
gunicorn
requests
```

Heroku log

```
   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119835+00:00 app[web.1]:     webhook_message = json.loads(my_json)

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119836+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119837+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _default_decoder.decode(s)

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119837+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119837+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119838+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119838+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.119838+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.120371+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.32.108 - - [06/Mar/2022:20:16:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"

   2022-03-06T20:16:12.120462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=apitradingview.herokuapp.com request_id=1e375b13-eeec-456b-9154-3935844eac7a fwd="96.74.1.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
```

git repo: https://github.com/HasanOu/trading_apps.git

Answer (score 1):

You can view the complete traceback of the heroku app:
Heroku dashboard -> App page -> Activity -> View Release Log.

There you can see what causes the problem. You can then debug it or if you post it here, people here can be more helpful.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I just added the log.

Comment: @user2512443 I don't see a log.

Comment: It is at the end of my post after "Heroku log". It says "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None"